# Pass state as props from parent to child and then update parent from child onSubmit

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component that renders a child component and passes it's initial state to the child component. I need a few clarifications- My gut feeling is to handle the event change in the Child component, is this correct? Upon submission, how do I pass the updated props back to parent? My gut is also telling that once the props is passed back to the parent, I can use componentDidUpdate() to set the state to be used elsewhere. If so, how?

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      arrival: "arrival",
      departure: "destination"
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
      // how to update state?
  }

  render() {
    const { arrival, departure } = this.state;
    return <Child arrival={arrival} departure={departure} />;
  }
}



class Child extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    this.handleSubmission = this.handleSubmission.bind(this);
  }


  handleSubmission(e){
    const target = e.target;
    const name = target.name;
    const value = target.value;

    // not sure how to handle props from here
   }


  render(){
    let { arrival, departure } = this.props;
    return(
      <form onSubmit = {this.handleSubmission} >
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="departure">Departure</label>
          <input type="" class="form-control" name="departure" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Departing Station"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="arrival">Arrival</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="arrival" id="inputArrival" placeholder="Enter Arriving Station"/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default Child
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@hello_there

Please disregard the previous answer, as it requires a lot more than just changing a few props.

I've forked the Sandbox and rewrote it here (so you can follow along).
[image: Edit so.answer.57279072]

I've outlined the steps to make the change to propagate to the parent below.

### Capture the states of `<input />`

First step is to capture the state of form fields.
There are two ways to handle form fields

1. [Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)
2. [Uncontrolled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) - discouraged

I am going to use the former (controlled) to capture the form field states by adding a state to `Form` component.

And you need to set the `value={...}` of each state and update each state from `onChange` event (using `handleInputChange` added below) for each form field.

*I've added  where changes were made*

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Form extends Component {
  // .. 
  state = {
    departure: "",
    arrival: ""
  };

  //... rest removed for brevity

  // ..  is used to update each form field state.
  handleInputChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };


  render() {
    const { departure, arrival } = this.state;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmission}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label> Departure</label>
          <input
            className="form-control"
            name="departure"
            placeholder="Enter Departing Station"
            // ...          ...
            value={departure} onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label> Arrival</label>
          <input
            className="form-control"
            name="arrival"
            id="inputArrival"
            placeholder="Enter Arriving Station"
            // ...         ...
            value={arrival} onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

### Update `App`'s state change event handler

Now we have states handy, we need to update the `App`'s `updateState` to accept a whole new state, so we don't make multiple method calls (`this.props.updateParentState`) and it'd let us pass a new reference so that React would know that the state has been changed in the `App` component.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      arrival: "arrival",
      departure: "departure"
    };
  }

  // From this 
  // updateState = (name, value) => {
  //   this.setState({
  //     [name]: value
  //   });
  // };

  // to this 
  updateState = newState => this.setState(newState);

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { arrival, departure } = this.state;
    console.log(`Arrival: ${arrival}, departure: ${departure}`);
  }

  render() {
    const { arrival, departure } = this.state;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Form
          arrival={arrival}
          departure={departure}
          //  stays the same
          updateParentState={this.updateState}
        />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

### Update `Child`'s submission event handler

Now the `App.updateState` accepts a state object, which can be used to update `App.state`, let's change `Child.handSubmission`.

```
  handleSubmission = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // this.props.updateParentState(name, value);
    this.props.updateParentState(this.state);
  };
```

You can see that `this.props.updateParentState(name, value)` has been replaced with `this.props.updateParentState(this.state)`, which would let us update `App.state` at once.

Now you should be able to see the change in the `App.componentDidUpdate`.

[image: working demo]

---

---

---

---

## OLD ANSWER - Disregard this

Changing the state in the child doesn't cause the re-render in the parent (so `componentDidUpdate` is probably not triggered by change in child component). So what you can do is to pass the event handler down to the child, which the child can notify the Parent component that something has changed.

I've explained the flow of how you can update the parent's states.

First you need to create a handler, with which you can update the Parent's state with.

```
updateState = (name, value) => this.setState({ [name]: value });
```

Here, I am using `[name]`, which is a dynamic property. So it should match up with the Parent's state name. In this case either `arrival` or `departure`.

Then you need to pass that event handler to the Child (you can name the prop name to whatever (In the code below, I used `updateParentState` but it can be `updateWhatever` so long as you pass it the `updateState` correctly).

```
<Child arrival={arrival} departure={departure} updateParentState={updateState} />
```

Here is the complete code that will update the parent state.
Changes are indicated with "" emoji below.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      arrival: "arrival",
      departure: "destination"
    };
  }

  // This is what you pass to the child as a `prop` to call.
  updateState = (name, value) => this.setState({ [name]: value });


  render() {
    const { arrival, departure } = this.state;
    // pass the event handler to the child component             ...  ...
    return <Child arrival={arrival} departure={departure} updateParentState={updateState} />;
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    this.handleSubmission = this.handleSubmission.bind(this);
  }


  handleSubmission(e){
    const target = e.target;
    const name = target.name;
    const value = target.value;

    //  Update the "Parent"'s state.
    // `name` & `value` will be the supplied to `Parent.updateState`
    this.props.updateParentState(name, value)
   }


  render(){
    // ... removed for brevity
  }
}
```

If the statement management gets too hard to manage with [prop-drilling](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling), then you can reach out for [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) (after familiarizing with it, you can check out [How to use React Context effectively](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively), which uses Hooks).
Or you can use [Redux](https://redux.js.org/).

Comment: Hey thanks for replying! I was reading your article on being able to display the updated state, however, on the re-render I cant seem to see the updated state in the console even after used the callback function that setState provides. 

Is it possible for you to take a look- https://codesandbox.io/s/submission-form-test-3q9zl

Comment: @hello_there I've re-wrote the answer completely, and disregard the previous answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. With Form having it's own state, I can see why Redux or Context can really be of use.

Comment: You're welcome. and yes, maintaining those state could be a mess as the app grows :) Now have fun and enjoy~

Answer (score 1):

Just pass to your children a reference on how to update the state:

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
    state = {departure : ''}

   setDeparture = departure => this.setState({ departure })

   render(){ <Child setDeparture={this.setDeparture} />  }
}

const Child = ({setDeparture}) => <button onClick={() => setDeparture('foo')}>Click</button>
```